# ExtendScript plugin for Webstorm or PhPstorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, extendscript

when scripting for after effects I often use ExtendScript.

There is an extendscript package available for sublime text out there.
https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/ExtendScript
(this makes it possible to run your script directly from sublime text into after effects)

I was wondering if there is also something like this out there for any JetBrains IDEs  (like WebStorm or PhpStorm etc.). I do know it has several plugins in it, but i don't know if there was ever one made for Expendscript like the one for sublime text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any... Please see http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5496889#5496889 for some hints
To be able to run adobe scripts from WebStorm, you can use external tools (Settings/External tools):

- create a new external tool
- specify a full path to Adobe tool capable of executing .jsx ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS5\Photoshop.exe", for example) as a 'Program'
- add $FileName$ as parameters
- set a working directory to $FileDir$
- make sure to check Show in/Project views and Editor menu to be able to run your tool from file right-click menu in Project view/Editor

then you'll be able to run your tool from a right-click menu of your .jsx file - the file will be passed to Photoshop as an argument